# Adding scrollbar in category dropdown

Tags: magento2, category, css, frontend, category-view

I add 1 category name `Category`, and add sub categories to it. But, because there's too much sub categories, i need to scroll down the page first to see the full list of the sub categories. So my plan is add scroll bar to the subcategory, then customer could see the full sub categories with scroll down. I tried to add some css code in `sections.phtml` like in code below, but it's not work, is there something i miss?

CSS :

```
<style type="text/css">
    nav ul li ul{
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
        height: 400px;
        max-height: 500px;
    }
</style>
```